# Parent entity type bundle - Is it possible in D8?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

**Issue:**
I got 7 different (article-like) node types. These types share 90% of their fields (means they have the same field base as well as same configured field instance).

**Problem:**
when a new mutaul field is coming, I have to add it 7 times. When I need to change the label (field instance level), I have to change it 7 times. When I write a form_alter, I need to address 7 different type of form_id's.

**Solution type am looking for:**
The best would be to have a parent node type entity. All the entity types which "extends" this entity type would have all the fields which parent has. As far as I know it's not possible.

Do you know any workarounds?

Comment: Are you sure you really need 7 different content type? I've faced your scenario in the past,  and I ended up with a single larger content type and some custom code for handling exceptions.

Comment: Since in the future, more article-like content type is about to come, handling all the time these exception would make the structure dirty. 

My final solution is to create a custom entity with predefined fields (which all custom entity types will have).

Comment: In custom PHP and PostgreSQL it is possible, you can create parent/child table and for each article type you can have different fields. Not sure what is your environment.

Comment: Look at the tags! D8!